# Managing the organisation chart as master data: the same term "unit B3" can change its meaning with every reorganisation

Tags: database, data-warehouse, enterprise

Our organisation is structured as a hierarchy of groups (A,  B,  C...) and units (A1,  B2 etc.)

The hierarchy is stored as terms in a master data database, with validity dates and additional properties. That way we know that unit B2 is "Audit Asia" while until last month it was "Legal Affairs".

However, systems like the contract management tool just use the code: Eg "contract 123456 is managed by unit B2"; my question is: how are we supposed to know *which* B2 is referred to?

As far as I can see there are two ways to do this:

1. every organisational entity has a unique id, "B2" is just the label displayed to the user - behind the scenes all the systems use behind the id.

We don't do this.

2. Everyone just uses the term / label "B2" but we make sure that every use of
   a term is dated.

   Eg if the contract information was last updated two months ago it must be referring to the previous version of B2, Legal Affairs.

We might be able to do this but it seems rather unreliable.

What is the standard way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is correct, because an identifier needs to be stable.

That said, another way to work around the problem is the managing entity for a contract is the entity called B2 during the life of the contract. In other words, make managing entity a slowly changing dimension type 2. I think this is what you mean by Option 2.

Option 1 is still correct. Fix your data. You're going to be in a world of reporting pain otherwise. I'm still struggling to see how a Master Data system could get this so wrong, but that is outside the scope of your question :)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to be sure I wasn't inventing problems; some colleague are pushing option 2. There must be a unique id somewhere - Active Directory SID? - but unfortunately no business key as such. If they need to distinguish people tend to use the title / description or the date of the reorganisation that created or replaced the unit.